# Does OxyPlot work in .NET 3.5?

Tags: wpf, charts, oxyplot

Is there any release of OxyPlot for .NET 3.5?

I couldn't find it in http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/, but maybe there is an old version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer is No. You'll need .Net 4.

If you'd like to read more, have a look at [this discussion](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/461916) on the oxyplot forum.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is. You can build OxyPlot for .NET 3.5 yourself from sources. [Here](http://oxyplot.org/documentation/build) is the description how to do this. Briefly, you can download source code from Git and open OxyPlot.WPF_NET35.sln file with Visual Studio (2010+). Just minor code modification is needed (2 loc).

Comment: The link is bad by now unfortunately.

Comment: Possibly, they have dropped .NET 3.5 support. I have just tried to build sources 2.5 years ago, and it worked.